# Custom postgreSQL domain with regex to accept a certain set of strings

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

In short, I'm trying to create a domain for strings that adhere to italian license plate syntax in *postgreSQL*. The layout is the following:

[**2 characters + 3 ditigs + 2 characters**]        (e.g. **GS220PN**)

So I figured I could use a regex, which according to PostgreSLQ documentation can be used by just using the ~* operator followed by a POSIX regex.

This is the code I came up with:

```
# create the domain
CREATE DOMAIN ITALIAN_LICENSE_PLATE AS VARCHAR(7) CHECK(
    VALUE ~* '/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}'
);

# create table
CREATE TABLE car (
plate ITALIAN_LICENSE_PLATE PRIMARY KEY
model VARCHAR(30)
make VARCHAR(30));

# insert test
INSERT INTO car(plate, model, make) VALUES
('DS331NA', 'A4', 'AUDI');
```

What I get is:

```
value for domain italian_license_plate violates check constraint "italian_license_plate_check".
```

Since 'DS331NA' is clearly 2 chars + 3 digits + 2 chars, something must be wrong with my regex.

I'm likely missing out on something trivial, but can anyone enlighten me?

EDIT: problem solved by top comment. Turns out a valid alternative would have been to use `SIMILAR TO` in place of `~*`.

So the following pieces of code are equivalent and they both work:

```
(...) CHECK( VALUE SIMILAR TO '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}')
(...) CHECK ( VALUE ~* '^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}$')
```

Comment: Your regex requires a `/`  character at the start of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}$'
```

Note the `/` at the start requires a `/` char to be the first char in the input, so it could not work.

The `^` anchor asserts the position at the start of the string and the `$` anchor asserts the position at the end of the string. They are somewhat redundant here as you indicated the allowed length when defining the type of data, but it is good practice to keep them in environments where automatic anchoring is not used.